# Render status 200 before executing code in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm integrating a communications api and whenever a text/voice reaches my server(rails controller), I have to send back an OK (200) to the api. I want to send this response before executing my code block because if my code breaks (and is unable to send the OK), the communcations api keeps sending the messages for up to 3 days. Now that just complicates the problem already on my server because it would keep breaking as the same message keeps on coming.

I did some research and found two solutions.

**Solution 1:** The first solution is below (my current implementation) and it doesnt seem to be working (unless I didnt read the log files properly or I'm hallucinating).

```
def receive_text_message
   head :ok, :content_type => 'text/html'   
   # A bunch of code down here
end
```

I thought this should do (per rails doc), but I'm not sure it does.

**Solution 2:** the second implementation which I'm contemplating is to quickly create a new process/thread to execute the code block and kill off the process that received the message...that way the api gets its OK very quickly and it doesnt have to wait on the successful execution of my code block. I could the spawnling (or spawn) gem to do this. I would go with creating a process since I use passenger (community) server. But new processes would eat up more RAM, plus I think it is harder to debug child processes/thread (i might be wrong on this)

Thanks for the help!

Side question: does rails attempt to restart a process after it just failed?

Comment: This might interest you http://edgar.tumblr.com/post/9880562940/how-to-return-a-real-empty-response-in-rails

Comment: I agree with Solution #2. You could be using something like Resque or Sidekiq, and queue jobs to be completed in their own time.

Comment: MrYoshiji I will take a look. @Kurt Funai I would rather not use Resque and co. But I think Sidekiq is a clean alternative to the Spawling gem. But just to be sure, once I call sidekiq's perform_async method in the controller above, will this controller then end and return?

Comment: I personally only have experience with Resque, but yes, after queueing a job the controller will continue executing. It does not wait for the utility server to process the job before continuing. Whatever you have after the perform_async would be executed (like your return).

Answer (score 3):

You could opt for returning a 200 in your controller and start a [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) job. That way the 200 will be returned immediately and your controller will be ready to process the next job. So no waste of time and resources in your controller. The let the worker to do the real hard job.

In your controller

```
def receive_text_message
   head :ok, :content_type => 'text/html'   
   HardWorker.perform_async(params)
end
```

In your sidekiq worker:

```
class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(params)
    # 'Doing hard work'
  end
end
```

I like sidekiq mostly because it is handling the resources more nicely compared to rescue.

Comment: @Boti...lol I think I like this option. It is a hybrid of the two solutions..I will try it out later this week. out of curiosity...so without sidekiq, are you saying my controller wont be able handle new requests until the code block executes completely?